# Json parsing using gson to get the location

Tags: android, json, gson

Please help me to write the POJO class for this Json result. I tried a lot but it doesn't work for me.This is the result return form google maps api

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Salem - Kochi - Kanyakumari Highway",
               "short_name" : "National Highway 47",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Thampanoor",
               "short_name" : "Thampanoor",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Thiruvananthapuram",
               "short_name" : "TVM",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Thiruvananthapuram",
               "short_name" : "TVM",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kerala",
               "short_name" : "KL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "695014",
               "short_name" : "695014",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Salem - Kochi - Kanyakumari Highway, Thampanoor, Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala 695014, India",
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use certain tools/website to generate POJO from JSON, one of such website is: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. On this website, you just need to paste your JSON response and it will generate required POJO classes. It does also support annotation styles like GSON and Jackson.

Be a lazy but a productive developer!

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt on how to create a POJO from a JSON, I'd recommend you to try this site: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

It outputs you a full java class that works for a given json type;

For most cases I'd recommend you to use this config (from the website above): Source type: Json Annotation style: None And check ONLY use primitives.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
public class Poi {

    @SerializedName("long_name")
    private String longName;

    @SerializedName("short_name")
    private String shortName;

    @SerializedName("types")
    private String[] types;
}
```

Then do it like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Poi> pois = new ArrayList<Poi>();

JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("results");

for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i ++) {
    pois.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i).toString(), Poi.class);
}
```